# Count number of unique genes by type

Tags: unix, awk

I'm new to this so please if this has been answered somewhere else kindly refer me to that question. I searched extensively and there are sort of similar questions but none are really applicable to my problem.

I want to count the number of unique names per class. I have a sheet with a list of names (column 1) and their class (column 2). I need to know how many unique names are in the list, per class. The list is tab delimited.

I think probably **awk** will be able to solve this quickly, but I'm really not that skilled in **awk**.

Example input:

```
 Name    Class
 ABCD    protein-coding 
 ABCD    protein-coding
 DCFG    lincRNA
 GTFR    lincRNA
```

Desired output:

```
 Class             Count
 protein-coding    1
 lincRNA           2
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat f
Name    Class
ABCD    protein-coding 
ABCD    protein-coding
DCFG    lincRNA
GTFR    lincRNA

$ awk 'FNR>1{a[$2]+=!( ($1,$2) in b); b[$1,$2]}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' f
lincRNA 2
protein-coding 1
```

Comment: @Fluorine you are welcome, I just made edit please use updated one

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the file and then get the unique value as follow:

code:

```
sort test_file.txt | uniq | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
1 protein-coding
2 lincRNA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately there are 50 different biotypes (or classes), so this is the reason I ask. It would be very laborious to do all 50 one by one.

Comment: This gives the number of all the names per class, not only unique ones. As you can see in my desired output it gives a count of 1 for protein-coding class. In yours the count is 2, as it gives non-unique ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{names[$2][$1]} END{for (class in names) print class, length(names[class])}' file
lincRNA 2
protein-coding 1
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{if (!seen[$2,$1]++) cnt[$2]++} END{for (class in cnt) print class, cnt[class]}' file
lincRNA 2
protein-coding 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If working with **uniq** and **sort**, a solution may be:

```
sed 1d input.tsv | sort -t $'\t' | uniq | awk '{print $2}' | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{print "Class\tCount"}{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

I skipped the headers with `sed 1d` and wrote an output file separated wth tabs.